# Does DB2 EXPLAIN command include cost of index update for INSERT statements

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We are currently looking at improving indexes we have on a set of tables. What I see in the EXPLAIN output is the performance improvement of certain SELECT queries when an appropriate index is created on a table. However I do not know whether or not EXPLAIN also includes the cost additional indexes incur on INSERT (and UPDATE) statements.

I have created a test insert statement but it shows the same cost in timerons regardless of the indexes I create on a certain table.

Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the [IBM manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_useexplain2capturesqlinfo.htm).

> EXPLAIN data contains information about the access path that DB2 uses to process SQL statements. The primary use of EXPLAIN data is to investigate the access paths for the SELECT parts of your statements. For example, the data in EXPLAIN tables describes:
>
> Whether an index access or table space scan is used for each access to a table.
>       When index access is used, how many indexes and index columns are used
>       Which types of I/O methods are used to read the data pages.
>       The join methods and types that are used, and the order in which DB2 joins the tables.
>       When and why DB2 sorts data rows.
>
> For UPDATE and DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF, and for INSERT, somewhat less information is provided. EXPLAIN data does not describe all or every type of access. For example, the access to LOB values, which are stored separately from the base table, and access to parent or dependent tables needed to enforce referential constraints, are not shown in EXPLAIN table data.

You'll need to experiment on a test DB2 system whether or not adding an index to help a SELECT perform better is worth the cost in INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES.  For most systems that have many more SELECTS than changes, the index cost is usually worthwhile.

Comment: I tried my SELECT and INSERT statements on a test DB. The estimated timeron cost for the SELECT statement did change when I changed the Index of the table. However the cost of the INSERT statement remained the same regardless of what kind of index I declared on the table. The info in the manual is unspecfic on whether or not the cost of associated index changes is included in the estimated cost of an INSERT statement. Any additional pointers on that?

Comment: @markus: Again, For UPDATE and DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF, and for INSERT, somewhat less information is provided.  So no, the INSERT explain is less than helpful.  Just run experiments using the actual select and insert statements on your test DB.

Comment: okay sorry for my comment. now i got your point. thanks for your effort.